# Expression Web 4 - Master Page Error

Tags: master-pages, expression-web

I created an ASP.Net Web Application in VS 2010.  That in turn creates an example Site.Master, Default.aspx, and several other example files.

I then opened Default.aspx in Expression Web 4 and get the error message

> The Master Page file 'Site.Master'
>   cannot be loaded.

Default.aspx can still be displayed fine in VS 2010.

Source.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApp.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            font-family: Tunga;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1 class="style1">
                    My Application 
                    Master Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Home/NewItem.aspx" Text="New Item" 
                                Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Home/AnotherItem.aspx" Text="Another Item" 
                                Value="Another Item"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx" Text="ContactUs" Value="ContactUs">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApp._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <style type="text/css">
    .style2
    {
        color: #669900;
    }
    .style3
    {
        background-color: #FFFFCC;
    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to MY page!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more <span class="style2"><strong><em><span class="style3">about</span></em></strong></span> ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Any idea how to get the master page to work properly in Expression Web 4?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Open Site option? (Click the yellow folder in the toolbar and then Open Site)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to menu bar and click on Site menu and then on Open Site now this way it'll open and work properly in the designer and now master page error.